# Python: Where to compile an RE?

Tags: python, performance

I have a function that iterates over a text file to extract certain information by using regular expressions to find the information.  But, the program goes over multiple files and so calls this function several times.

Currently, I have the regular expressions compile as the first steps of the function.  But I started wondering if this is good design from a programming perspective since the function gets called several times.

Is the interpreter smart enough to see that these do not change and cache them away between runs?  Alternatively I considered compiling them as global variables so that it would always be available only compiled once, but that separates the regex from the place it will be used which makes it harder to read.  The other option I looked at was creating the function as a closure with regex values passed in when it is created, but that seemed unnecessarily complex.

**In short, What is the most efficient way to compile the RE's (or any other value which is calculated once) that is still readable and pythonic?**

Thank you.

Comment: I believe this is a case of premature optimization. Just do whatever you feel is most readable in your situation. If you have performance issues, run a profiler and see what's the problem.

Comment: @AmirRachum In this particular case, you are probably right.  But this isn't the first or last time I will have a design like this so its nice to get it right early, at least when that doesn't harm readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's regex module does cache the compiled versions of recently-used regexes, so you can probably remove the explicit compiles and not have an issue.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @AmirRachum: yes. Up to 512 last patterns are cached in Python 3.3 by default, see [re.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/28c25ae338fa/Lib/re.py#l266). It was [100 in Python 2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/re.py#l224)

Comment: Thanks.  Sounds like trusting the cache is the way to go unless a very large number of patterns are being used.

Answer (score 1):

OBLIGATORY NOTE: Always make sure this is your bottleneck before going down this rabbit hole.  If you only run the regular expression a few times, and if the regex isn't particularly complicated, the time savings are probably minimal.

Your best bet is to use `re.compile` if you plan on running the regex operations many times.  However, without more details, the most that can be said is: you should test explicitly.  Use the timeit or other modules to time the process.

As for caching the compiled regular expressions, regardless of whether it does in the background, you will pay a penalty for using the re functions directly rather than compiling first.  To see this, you should use `dis` to see what it does:

```
>>> def f():
...     x="foo bar baz"
...     return re.match("foo", x)
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo bar baz')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (re)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                1 (match)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('foo') ** always have to pass the regex
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             21 RETURN_VALUE
>>> n=re.compile("foo")
>>> def g():
...     x="foo bar baz"
...     return n.match("foo")
...
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo bar baz')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (n)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                1 (match)
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

So even if it does cache the regular expression in the background, the plan must involve passing the regular expression to `re.match` (it is unavoidable).  The compiled version avoids that step.

Comment: Since Python automatically caches recent regexes, you only really need to explicitly compile if you're going to be running a lot (think hundreds) of different regexes repeatedly, many times each.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple `RegexCache` class. Something like (untested):

```
class RegexCache(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}

    def get(self, pattern):
        if pattern not in self.cache:
            self.cache[pattern] = re.compile(pattern)

        return self.cache[pattern]
recache = RegexCache()
```

Then, instead of:

```
re.search(complex_pattern, whatver)
```

you do:

```
re.search(recache.get(complex_pattern), whatver)
```

This keeps the pattern together with where it is used yet also ensures that patterns you use multiple times will be compiled. You'll also have to make sure the cache doesn't get too large.

Comment: Don't do this - Python already caches for you; you're just adding more overhead.

Comment: @Amber: maybe, depends how many regexes you use I guess. There's also explicit is better than implicit. Also if you exceed the python cache size it just clears the whole thing at once, so if you have say `CACHE_SIZE + 1` regexes that you use all in a row it won't end up caching anything.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with having the re's compiled and available as module-level objects. Not that it's always current best practice, but it's what's used in various modules in the stdlib.

To me, using module-level compiled re objects would be preferable to 3.3's caching as the cache relies on an implementation detail that you likely have not much control over (or could change in future versions). Defining them at module scope makes it obvious to the reader of your code that they're compiled once and used N times.